# How to pass Angular variable into jQuery function

Tags: jquery, angular

I think this should be fairly simple, but for the life of me I can't get it working.

I have an angular string (placeholder) that I would like to reference from a jQuery function that's fired on $document.ready(). Basically this is what I have:

```
placeholder: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.translateService.get(['']).subscribe(translations => {
      this.placeholder = this.translateService.instant('placeholder');
      console.log('PLACEHOLDER', this.placeholder);  <<<<<<<<< has expected value
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
      console.log('READY', this.placeholder);   <<<<<<<<< undefined
      $('#dropDown').select2({
        placeholder: this.placeholder,
        data: [
            ...
        ]
      });
    });        
}
```

How do I reference this.placeholder from within the jQuery function?

Comment: in document.ready this is refering to window object not to angular obj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `function` keyword, it defines its own `this`, which overrides the outer `this` you believed to use:

```
this.placeholder = 'Foo';
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log('READY', this.placeholder); // this is another this, local to the function
}
```

There are two solutions:

### With old JS

In pure JS you could just move away your outer `this` to use it inside:

```
this.placeholder = 'Foo';
var that = this;
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log('READY', that.placeholder); // that refers to the outer this
}
```

### With modern JS (ECMA script >5)

If you can use a modern browser with ECMA script >5, you can use the arrow function `() => {}` instead of `function() {}`, which automatically preserves the outer this:

```
this.placeholder = 'Foo';
$(document).ready(() => {
  console.log('READY', this.placeholder); // () => {} does not override this
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like below code. remove document.ready and function keyword

use arrow function to keep this in scope.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

placeholders:Array<string> = [];

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
  // removed function keyword and added () => {} syntax
  $('#btn').on('click', (e, arr) => {  
    console.log(this.placeholders);
  });
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue where I could not reach an angular service that had been passed in through the constructor from the jquery function.  Simply removing the function keyword gave me access.  Thank you!